# What is the meaning of "quote" in the following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I know one of the meanings of "quote" is "a quotation giving the estimated cost for a particular job or service". But I wonder if it means the same in the following context. I haven't heard the phrase "doing a quote" before.

> ‘I couldn’t get hold of you. Your phone’s going straight to
> answerphone. Richard’s out for an hour doing a quote, so I thought I’d
> pop over.’

Comment: Yes, if Richard is a builder, plumber or similar, it probably means 'inspecting a job with a view to giving the householder a quote'.

Comment: Sounds like your guess is right. Is Richard someone who gives out quotes for potential projects?

Comment: Someone may well speak of 'doing a visit' if this is to do work (health workers, some hairdressers ...); 'doing a quote' seems a broadened version. 'Out doing a shoot' (for a film crew) is more logically phrased.

Answer (score 1):

"Quote" is an abbreviated form of "quotation":

> OED:
>
> **Quotation** (n.) **7.** An amount stated as the price of a stock or of any commodity for sale. **Also: a contractor's stated price for a particular job.**
>
> 1944   R. V. Boughton in R. Greenhalgh Pract. Builder xii. 378/2 *There are usually conditions which make it very prudent to obtain many quotations for each job as it is estimated.*
>
> **Quote** (n.)
>
> **3. = quotation n. 7.**
>
> 1934   Brainerd (Minnesota) Daily Dispatch 31 Dec. 3/5   *The following are today's custom smelters' quotes for delivered copper (cents per pound).*
>
> 1996   Voice 25 June 32/1   *This is an excellent time to gather quotes and estimates with a view to home or garden improvements.*